# display RGB image both in windows and mono linux platform

Tags: c#, linux, windows, winforms, mono

I want to run one .NET application in to my Linux PC using mono command.

```
mono application.exe
```

I got some little bit success and received GUI which is same as running on windows. so i am happy to see the GUI on my Linux platform.

Then, I want to display one image into window which are displayed perfect on windows platform.

But when i tried to run the same .net application using mono command on my Linux platform then i could not got success to display image which are displayed on windows platform.

please see the following code reference to display the image into windows platform.

```
byte[] data_rgb;
data_rgb = new Byte[HEIGHT * WIDTH * 3];
public const int HEIGHT = 1944;
public const int WIDTH = 2592;

fixed (byte* bPtr = data_rgb)
{
    IntPtr pSrc = (IntPtr)bPtr;
    bmp = new Bitmap(WIDTH, HEIGHT, STRIDE, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, pSrc);
}
```

The data_rgb is the data buffer coming from hardware which is around 6 MB RGB data.

Is anyone have idea about why above functionality not working on Linux platform using mono utility?

Also, please let me know if there is any other way to display image using other library in windows which can be supported into Linux platform using mono frame to display the image.

One more question that how can i refresh the windonw which is run by mono command? Because whenever i ran the .NET binary using mono utility then minimized or maximized the window then at that it can not be minimized or maximized properly as compare to windows.

How to refresh the window in linux using mono?

Comment: give more details about pSrc

Comment: Here is the following data which you need regarding pSrc

Comment: Here is the following data which you need regarding pSrc.                                                                byte[] data_rgb;                                               data_rgb = new byte[HEIGHT * WIDTH * 3];                        fixed (byte* bPtr = data_rgb)
{
     IntPtr pSrc = (IntPtr)bPtr;

    bmp = new Bitmap(WIDTH, HEIGHT, STRIDE, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, pSrc);
}

Here the data_rgb is the total buffer which is around 2 MB data converted from raw data into RGB 24bit data.

Comment: {
 IntPtr pSrc = (IntPtr)bPtr;
 bmp = new Bitmap(WIDTH,HEIGHT,STRIDE,PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb, pSrc);
}

Comment: so, basically, pSrc is pointer to rgb buffer data which has RGB data coming from driver.

Comment: It's better that you edit your question, to add the code about pSrc, than adding it into a comment

Comment: I have added the code which you need. so please let me know if you need any more information....

Comment: what do yoou mean with "coming from hardware"?

Comment: The data "data_rgb" coming from my USB device which i got correct as i have verified from my side as well as in .net application. And one more thing that the data "data_rgb" is RGB data which can be directly displayed on window using System.Drawing.Imaging class in .NET on windows platform successfully without any issue. But i can not display the same image on Linux side using mono command.

Comment: I have also added some .so library which are required to run that .net binary on my Linux platform using mono command.

Comment: I got GUI in window on my Linux PC but fails to display the RGB image data which i got from the hardware using mono command. can anyone have idea about System.Drawing class can create any problem on Linux side to display the image?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not about Mono and the Bitmap class.

The problem is where your image data comes from: you mention it comes from a USB device. But how do you access your device from your .NET code? Seems like you're using IntPtr, which leads me to think that you're using [P/Invoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_Invocation_Services).

P/Invoke is inherently a technique that is not cross platform. You should stick to **managed code** if you want your program to work across platforms (Linux and Windows) with no specific-platform code.

UPDATE: You mention that you have a ".so" library to access the platform-specific functionality on Linux. Then this may be the bit that is not working. You should post a brand new question on stackoverflow with the code you're using to P/Invoke that library in Linux.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I can able to get USB data from device using .so file which i have imported in place of .dll file. I got correct data from device to that rgb buffe. so there is no any hardware dependency over there.

Comment: then maybe you found a mono bug in your specific scenario: maybe the bug only happems when using PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb enum? You should do some testing. And later file a bug in http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/

Comment: do you have more idea about how to debug this issue from Linux side?

Comment: yes, finding a case that works, and then looking at the code ( https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/System.Drawing/System.Drawing/Bitmap.cs ) to find out why in your case it doesn't

Comment: SO. this code works to display the image on both .NET in windows platform and on mono in Linux platform. correct?

Comment: Let me know if you find any more information regarding this issue or stuff.

Comment: Thanks for you valuable reply.

Comment: I got some success to convert raw data into RGB data but the image which are converted into RGB data is not as windows has converted in form of color bitmaps. Windows application can display the execat image which i need but using mono the image becomes blur as well as it shows as black & white image.

Comment: I have also read docs of mono and found that it supports System.Drawing class which need to display the image. I have also looked into bitmap class which is same as windows used. But still fails to display the image which  are displayed into windows machine. Do yoy have any idea about what is happening here?

Comment: Is there any limitation of mono utility to display any .bmp and .png image using System.Drawing class on Linux platform? because when i ran the same .Net binary on windows platform than it works fine with proper .bmp image display on the form. But when i ran the same binary using mono on Linux platform then i got black & white image in stead of colored image with some bad property. Please let me know if you have any information regarding this issue.

Comment: I don't have any information, you may have found a bug in mono (more particular, in libgdiplus code https://github.com/mono/libgdiplus/), I hope you can fix the bug! (and I hope you contribute the bugfix later to libgdiplus in the form of a pull request)

Comment: so, you mean that it may be the issue of libgdiplus which i am using in my Linux platform while running the .NET binary using mono utility. right?

Comment: I have also reviewed the .bmp file which is generated from windows platform as well as on Linux platform and found that there is data mismatch in both file which is viewed in hexadecimal editor.

Comment: ok, then maybe the data mismatch is the problem, and there is no mono bug

Comment: Ya I know that but how to confirm that the issue is not from mono side because i have run the same application and created one .bmp file and displayed on windows which looks fine as per our requirement but that binary is not working on Linux platform using mono utility.

Comment: One more thing that the .bmp file is generated from .NET binary using Bitmap concept of System.Drawing class.

Comment: what do you think about this issue?

Comment: why don't you load the binary data from a file in Linux (a file that you could generate in Windows directly from the hardware), then try to use that data, and if it works, then there's no Mono bug

Comment: Is there any settings in the Bitmap function to set the pixel format or other image related settings to save the image into Linux?

Comment: My actual requirement is to load display the RGB24 bit data on window which is coming directly from the hardware. And, I have to capture that live data from my Linux PC because that device is also connected to MY Linux PC.

Comment: And, We have to run the same application on both windows and Linux PC at same time. so there is no any way which you are talking.

Comment: I have already tried by your way and its worked but i have capture live data in Linux PC from the hardware which is directly connected into My Linux PC.

Comment: if it worked, then the problem lies somewhere in the way you get the data in linux

Comment: @RiteshPrajapati, you will have to debug into libgdiplus and System.Drawing on Linux so as to better understand how it works under the hood and why it fails. I met other bugs in that area and I am completed defeated by the burden to locate the cause. If possible, switch to GTK#. WinForms on Mono is far from production quality, and you hit issues almost at every yard (especially when you use pointers and unmanaged stuffs).

Comment: so, you mean that there is the issue in libgdiplus library which is used to display image on Linux using mono. I have also created one more sample application which can browse one PNG formated image displayed on form which works fine on Linux using mono utility.

Comment: Do you have other library related idea to solve this issue? Because i can not move from mono to other as i have to run .NET binary into linux anyway which is customer's requirement. So, Please help me to solve this issue in mono.

Comment: @Lex Li, It is to hard to move from mono to other framework because the application is already developed in .NET which i have to run into Linux Platform and we have to deliver .exe file for both windows and Linux. Please suggest me reliable way to solve this issue.

Comment: I have looked into image file which is generated from hardware data and compared with windows generated data and found that i got black and white color data perfect but i could not get REG, GREEN and BLUE data which is also available into data which is coming from the hardware.

Comment: GTK# is another GUI framework, but still part of Mono. The only effort required is to redo the GUI design. GTK# provides better integration with Linux OS. http://pinta-project.com/ is an open source project based on GTK# and you can see it is capable of handling complex image operations.

Comment: I don't have much time to design whole GUI and its related thread programming which has already done in windows. so is there any other library which can be used to load RGB24 bit data using bit mapping concept?

Comment: I think that there  is not any WPF (Windows Platform Foundation) support in mono. correct? Do you have any idea about other alternative tool to support WPF in linux?

Comment: Now, I can display the same image in using mono which can be displayed on windows using the same binary on both side without any issue.

Comment: then it is a problem in how your library extracts the binary in Linux

Comment: Actually, I have to add the header of 54 bytes in front of the every image while displaying the image in Linux while it is not required in Windows platform using Bitmap concept.

Comment: I have one more question regarding mono is that do i need to install mono on every machine on which i have to run the same binary which are compiled through gmcs command from .NET binary? Because, At the end i have to give one binary to our client which is going to run over Linux PC. I have my modified usb driver as well as my shared object file and Binary which is compiled using gmcs command of .NET source. Please let me know if you have any idea about this.

Comment: Please let me know if anyone have answer of above question.